# I can I manually specify BSON type in mongodb's NodeJS Driver? I am getting error if I use "$numberLong"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bson, int64

This is How I am framing the document's object before inserting it to the collection

```
function newTupple(name, email){
return {
  email:email,
  name:name,
  account_status:{
    email_verified:{                  //I want this in Int64
        "$numberLong": `${Date.now()}`
    },
    activated:false
  }
}
}
```

Then I Insert it like

```
const new_doc = newTupple("Ninja", "jojo@something.com")
collection.insertOne(new_doc, (err, result)=>{
if(err){
    //err: returns " key $numberLong must not start with '$' "
}
}
```

I am using npm package `mongodb@3.6.0`

What am I doing wrong? Or is custom data type not available for JS?

......................................

Update

......................................

Full Error Log

```
Error: key $numberLong must not start with '$'
    at serializeInto (--------------\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:915:19)
    at serializeObject (--------------\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (--------------\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:941:17)
    at serializeObject (--------------\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (--------------\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:941:17)
    at serializeObject (--------------\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (--------------\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:727:17)
    at serializeObject (--------------\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (--------------\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:941:17)
    at BSON.serialize (--------------\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\bson.js:64:28)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using extended json syntax which is inappropriate for constructing object graphs in an application. Instead you should be constructing objects of appropriate types.

For example see [here](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson#node-no-bundling) for a Long example.

```
const BSON = require('bson');
const Long = BSON.Long;

const doc = { long: Long.fromNumber(100) };
```