# mongoengine: update document with date field fails with << self.error('cannot parse date "%s"' % value) >>

Tags: python, mongodb, date, mongoengine

Mongoengine is really beginning to be a pain in the a**.

I am querying a document via Python/Mongoengine from a MongoDB collection that contains a creation date.

I converted the whole output with to_json() to a json string

```
    document = Qkey.objects(id=id)
    djson = document.to_json()
```

which then contains this:

```
...
"date_created": {
    "$date": 1595784271766
},
...
```

I then put the whole JSON structure into a textarea field in a web application to let the user make changes to the JSON data (usually he will not make changes to the "date_created" value but to some other fields).

I read in the whole textarea and convert it back from a large string to a Python dictionary.

As expected, the dictionary item looks like this when being printed:

```
date_created: {'$date': 1595784271766}
```

However, when I then try to update() the whole Mongoengine document, I get this error stack:

```
  File "/webupdate/app/edit.py", line 38, in update_document
    document.update(**attributes_json)
  File "/webupdate/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 530, in update
    update = transform.update(queryset._document, **update)
  File "/webupdate/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/transform.py", line 317, in update
    value = field.prepare_query_value(op, value)
  File "/webupdate/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/fields.py", line 593, in prepare_query_value
    return super().prepare_query_value(op, self.to_mongo(value))
  File "/webupdate/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/base/fields.py", line 196, in prepare_query_value
    self.validate(value)
  File "/webupdate/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/fields.py", line 536, in validate
    self.error('cannot parse date "%s"' % value)
  File "/webupdate/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/base/fields.py", line 171, in error
    raise ValidationError(message, errors=errors, field_name=field_name)
mongoengine.errors.ValidationError: cannot parse date "None"
```

When I remove date_created completely, the update works.

I hope anyone can point me in the right direction how to handle date fields via JSON to Python dicts to update a whole MongoDB document.

Answer (score 0):

[Everywhere in the documentation](https://pythonise.com/series/mongodb-and-python/mongodb-python-mongoengine-pt1) it appears that a DateTimeField is updated using Python's datetime object. Have you tried converting that timestamp into a datetime in that map used in update_document:

```
date_created: {'$date': datetime.fromtimestamp(1595784271766) }
```

Let me know if that helps.

**Edit** basing on this fragment (lines: 533 - 536 in site-packages/mongoengine/fields.py, mentioned in OP's error) it appears that problem might indeed be with `value` not being a date or datetime instance:

```
def validate(self, value):
    new_value = self.to_mongo(value)
    if not isinstance(new_value, (datetime.datetime, datetime.date)):
        self.error('cannot parse date "%s"' % value)
```

Not sure if `self.to_mongo(value)` does not return None earlier, though.

Comment: The datetime construction is moving in the right direction but using it with extended json syntax (`$date`) is unlikely to work for the reason stated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63468445/i-can-i-manually-specify-bson-type-in-mongodbs-nodejs-driver-i-am-getting-erro/63473672#63473672.

Comment: But this seems to be totally different driver, not sure why would you compare them. You've got an additional layer (mongoengine) - a **python** library with its own logic. Basing on the error, something is certainly being done with date in the application layer prior to actually committing a db transaction.

Comment: All drivers behave essentially the same with respect to the behavior being discussed. The only code that knows what `$date` is in a MongoDB driver is the extended json parsing code. Libraries built on top of drivers don't deal with extended json serialization either.

Comment: Okay, I'm not an expert so you might be right. However, the implementation suggests that mongoengine expects date/datetime instances in various places.

Comment: "Flattening" that date entirely before calling `update_document` might also be worth trying: `date_created: datetime.fromtimestamp(1595784271766)` as @D.SM suggests.

Comment: That should work once you handle everything else in https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/extended-json.rst#conversion-table.

Comment: @Marek: If have actually tried to convert that strange number into a datetime object, however that lead to the message "ValueError: year 52536 is out of range". So that number is not a "normal" timestamp but has some other base. I really wonder why the to_json() function creates such a garbled mess that you manually have to convert into something else before you can you reuse it as an input to a Mongoengine document again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with mongoengine but you appear to have serialized a document to extended json using the `to_json` call. To reverse this you need to parse extended json into a proper python object structure using for example the method described [here](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html). Generally you cannot parse extended json with a plain json parser and use the resulting  type-annotated raw document as input to methods that require objects of "normal" language types.

Comment: Sorry, but I still have no idea what to do exactly.