# Golang MongoDB Changing decimal value to int

Tags: mongodb, go

I am using MongoDB and Golang-mongo Drive to fetch the data. but I am getting discrepancy while fetching value.
Field - MinimumOrderAmount

```
Value stored in MongoDB = 399.0
```

Struct -

```
MinimumOrderAmount        float64            `json:"minimum_order_amount" bson:"minimum_order_amount"`
```

spew.Dump(data.MinimumOrderAmount) output

```
399
```

Expected Output

```
399.0
```

in Json string also value shown without 0

```
"minimum_order_amount": 399
```

and then that JSON fails in front end with error int is not subtype of double.

if stored value is 399.5 then I get correct 399.5 but how to prevent the golang driver converting from float to int?

Comment: `399` and `399.0` are equal numbers. How you print them is a different topic. Print it like `fmt.Printf("%.1f", data.MinimumOrderAmount)`.

Comment: Issue is JSON , it shows as     "minimum_order_amount": 399, and then in front end it fails with error int it not subtype of double.

Comment: All drivers should expose BSON types. When you provide instances of those as values, the driver should store the data using the specified type. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63468445/i-can-i-manually-specify-bson-type-in-mongodbs-nodejs-driver-i-am-getting-erro/63473672#63473672 for a JS example.

Comment: @max Also note that the error in your comment is the client's error. In JSON there are no integers and floating point number, just numbers. It's the client that makes assuption that `399` is (or should be) an integer. In JSON `399` and `399.0` are equivalent.

Comment: I saw your solution on other thread. Changes are big since I have many such struct in various files . Now I have to decide whether to change front end or backend.

Comment: Again, repeating myself, since in JSON `399` and `399.0` are equivalent, client shouldn't treat them differently. Client should accept both forms if it claims to be handling JSON.

Comment: Client is written in Dart which uses PODO to handle JSON ( Plain OLD Dart Object ) . Same code creates web app , android app and Ios App. when it is compiled in web app ( Javascript )  it works file .  when android apk is build same code is throwing error.